# ButtonClick event not adding data

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

So I have the following code but the database isn't being update and the page doesn't seem to be displaying any error. There are no errors in the build but still no data goes in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class ValidateMe : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Movie;Integrated Security=True");

        connection.Open();

        if (TextBox8.Text == TextBox9.Text)
        {
            string UserName = TextBox7.Text;
            string Password = TextBox8.Text;
            string FirstName = TextBox1.Text;
            string LastName = TextBox2.Text;
            string Address = TextBox3.Text;
            string PostCode = TextBox4.Text;
            string Phone = TextBox5.Text;
            string Email = TextBox6.Text;

            string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `address`, `postcode`, `phone`, `email`, `level`) VALUES (NULL, '@UserName', '@FirstName', '@LastName', '@Password', '@Address', '@PostCode', '@Phone', '@Email');";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Missing  something? Build a command, adding parameters and executing??

Comment: Uh... there is so much wrong with this code. Please, search the web on how to insert data into database using c# since it is going to be hard to address all issues here. You are not closing/disposing connection, you are not executing command you've prepered, you are not passing parameters into command - that's starters. On web there will be enough info to get you started - and it is quite simple so no worries!

Comment: do not forget to close the connection ;-) use parameters with the command and execute it after parameter binding.

Answer (score 2):

Your code misses a few (fundamental) steps.

After opening the connection you should do:

- build the command
- add the parameters required by the command
- execute it
- close the connection

Like this

```
string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, password," + 
                  "address, postcode, phone, email, level) VALUES " + 
                  "(@UserName, @FirstName, @LastName, @Password, " + 
                  "@Address, @PostCode, @Phone, @Email);";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
.....
// Add the other parameters
.....

// Execute the query
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Close the connection
connection.Close();
```

You don't have to put backsticks around your field names (SqlServer doesn't require them), also the parameter names should not be enclosed in single quotes.

And one last note. If `user_id` is an Identity field then you don't need to add to the commandtext.

Comment: I've added it in but I think that the SQL connection isn't working as the data still isn't going in 


        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5/SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Movie;Integrated Security=True");

Comment: If there is something wrong in the connectionstring then you should have an error when you try to open the connection